# Open a file given by the result of a command in vim

Tags: linux, bash, vim, find

I find myself doing the following almost every day

1. Run a find (`find -name somefile.txt`)
2. Open the result in `vim`

The problem is I have to copy and paste the result of the `find` into the `vim` command.  Is there any way to avoid having to do this?  I have experimented a bit (`find -name somefile.txt | vim`) but haven't found anything that works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use command substitution:

```
vim $(find -name somefile.txt)
```

or

```
find -name somefile.txt -exec vim {} \;
```

Comment: This will try to open all the 'somefile.txt'

Comment: that's what is required. We need to open the file found for editing.

Comment: ok. If that is what is needed, then 
find -name somefile.txt | xargs vim

Comment: No, that doesn't work properly and might even mess up your terminal! You can't pipe to xargs vim, because vim expects input to come from an interactive terminal.

Comment: Vim emits an alert, but it still works in the end.

Comment: An anonymous user notes that [this will fail if the filename has spaces](http://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1082)

Comment: `vim $(find -name somefile.txt)` works but I'm always annoyed to have to do this, especially when the command inside the `$(...)` is usually the last command you entered and I just want to pipe it to vim. `pvim` does that - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30208/14810

Comment: Another alternative would be `vim \`find -name somefile.txt\``. @StuartPowers Alternatively, you can use `vim \`!-1\`` if you already used this find was you previous command

Comment: @balki to use xargs in this scenario, you have to use the flag -o, it's in the man:

-o      Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before executing the command.  This is useful if you want xargs to run an interactive application.

Comment: @dogbane $ find /etc/update-motd.d -type f -exec vim {} < /dev/null \;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13555918

Comment: Note that the second option opens one vim instance for every single file. This causes can cause plenty of inconveniences, for example, you may ending up closing vim several dozens of times.

Comment: You can use this to open each file in a new tab `find . -name '*file_name*' -exec vim -p {} +;`

Comment: To adjust the result supplied, you might wish to adjust it with cut ofc `echo 'someletters_12345_moreleters.ext' | cut -d'_' -f 2` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash/428118#428118

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

1. start vim
2. in vim, use the following:

`:r!find /<path> -name 'expression'`

The results should appear in vim when the search is complete.

Or

Try:

```
find /<path> -name > results.txt
vim results.txt
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question at all. You're printing the content of the file in the current buffer, not actually **opening the file**.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind running the command again: press <kbd>Up</kbd> and append an `xargs` command. Or use history substitution and run

```
!! | xargs vim          # won't work with file names containing \'" or whitespace
!! | xargs -d \\n vim   # GNU only (Linux, Cygwin)
```

There's a lightweight way of saving the output of a command that works in ksh and zsh but not in bash (it requires the output side of a pipeline to be executed in the parent shell). Pipe the command into the function `K` (zsh definition below), which **k**eeps its output in the variable `$K`.

```
function K {
    K=("${(@f)$(tee /dev/fd/3)}") 3>&1;
}
find … |K
vim $K
```

Automatically saving the output of each command is not really possible with the shell alone, you need to run the command in an emulated terminal. You can do it by running inside [`script`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=script&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE&format=html) (a BSD utility, but available on most unices including Linux and Solaris), which saves all output of your session through a file (there's still a bit of effort needed to reliably detect the last prompt in the typescript).

Answer (score 3):

I like to to use the Command substitution

```
> vim $(find . -name somefile.txt)
```

The `$( ... )` executes the command inside the braces and the output can then be used by the command. The above will find all files somefile.txt thus allowing you to use `:next` to move through all the files.

Its very usefull if you spend a couple of tries refining the command, because you can then use history substitution to repeat the command for the editor.

```
> find . -name somefile.txt
./debug/somefile.txt
./somefile.txt
> vi $( !! )
```

Comment: I usually use `$(...)` for command substitution rather than backticks. See [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) for reasons.

Comment: @Ingo Yep nodays I would to.

Answer (score 2):

I must have missed the point here, because I would use:

```
:find **/somefile.txt
```

(if I knew there was only one in my   `:echo &path`   ) or, if I wanted them all:

```
:args **/somefile.txt
```

Edit: Whoa! Ok, so I *did* miss the point - you want the find list, not the actual files opened? Try (again, from within Vim):

```
!!find . -name somefile.txt
```

-- my bad :)

Answer (score 2):

As @davidmh pointed in the comments, you can use `xargs` with the flag `-o` if you want to use an interactive application.

```
find . -name somefile.txt | xargs -o vim
```

If you do not use `-o`, you will probably mess up the terminal state after leaving vim. If you have done it, you should be able to reset your terminal with the following command:

```
reset
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function `pvim` which does what you want.  If multiple lines are piped to `pvim` it ignores all but the first, it could be extended though to open multiple files in vim.

```
stu@sente ~ $ function pvim() { read -r somefile; exec < /dev/fd/1; vim "$somefile"; }
stu@sente ~ $ type pvim
pvim is a function
pvim ()
{
    read -r somefile;
    exec < /dev/fd/1;
    vi "$somefile"
}
```

Use it like:

```
stu@sente ~ $ find . -name "foo.txt" | pvim
```

which will load the first "foo.txt" into vim just as if you had typed:

`vim $(find . -name "foo.txt | head -n1")`

Answer (score 1):

To open all files found in individual tabs, you can:

```
vim -p $(find -name somefile.txt)
```

or

```
find -name somefile.txt -exec vim -p {} +;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `xargs -o vim`

I added the following to my `.bash_aliases`

```
# .bash_aliases

### Example Usage: "ls | sort -r | pipe-vim"
alias pipe-vim="xargs -o vim"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler `xargs` solution than those already mentioned:

```
find -name somefile.txt | xargs vim -p
```

The `-p` option tells `vim` to open each file in a separate tab. I find this more convenient than using buffers.

Answer (score 0):

I found that opening a file with the help of `locate` in vim is extremely convenient and much faster than `find`.

The following command searches a file called `app.py` in the path containing the directory `MyPythonProject`.

```
:args `locate '*MyPythonProject*app.py'`
```