# Open multiple files in Vim with a filelist

Tags: bash, vim

I have a file 'filelist' that contains the following lines:

```
text1.txt
text2.txt
text3.txt
```

I am looking for a command line invocation that opens the 3 files in vim. I tried the following:

```
$ cat filelist | vim -
```

and

```
$ vim < cat filelist
```

but those do not yield the desired result.

Comment: Try `vim $(cat filelist)`.

Answer (score 15):

If the file names don't contain spaces or other *problematic* characters, you can use

```
vim $(cat filelist)
```

For file names with spaces, using `xargs` is more robust (here using GNU `xargs` specific options):

```
xargs --delimiter '\n' --arg-file=filelist vim --
```

Comment: What a quick answer! Great :) I found another solution on this site using `backticks` (on the same key as the ~ sign). Here it is: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5882/37057

Comment: `$(…)` is the same as backticks, but a little more robust, since they can't be confused with single quotes or other similar looking characters and they can be nested.

Comment: This solution is simple and versatile.  To navigate use `:next` or `:n` and `:prev` or `:p`. Check more detail here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27590/140751 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27589/140751

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
vim -- ${(f)"$(<filelist)"}
```

With `bash` 4.0+:

```
readarray -r files < filelist &&
  vim -- "${files[@]}"
```

With any Bourne-like shell (including `zsh` and `bash`):

```
(IFS='
'; set -f; exec vim -- `cat filelist`)
```

With GNU `xargs` (also using `-r` to avoid running `vim` if the file is empty, but contrary to the other approaches, not skipping the empty lines if any):

```
xargs -rd '\n' -a filelist vim --
```

Comment: Why not just `➜  vim $(<filelist)` in the first example? Is it wrapped into parameter expansion just because `(f)` will handle properly filenames with spaces?

Comment: @branquito, yes `(f)` splits on line **f**eeds, `$(<filelist)` would split on any character of `$IFS` (by default SPC, TAB, LF and NUL) and in `ksh` ([where that `$(<` operator comes from](/a/368663)) and `bash` (but not `zsh` unless in `sh`/`ksh`/`bash` emulation), would also do globbing so characters like `?`, `*`, `[` would also be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

To open all *index.php* in the current working path

```
vim -p `find . -name index.php`
```

Comment: Simple and very useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already inside vim, you can set `:args` from inside vim:

```
:args file-1 file-2 ... file-n
```

Bonus, on Unix you can also do:

```
:args `find . -name Makefile`
```

(assuming file paths don't contain newline characters, and that there's at least one matching file)

Or in your case:

```
:args `cat filelist`
```