# Opening files in vim with a filelist not working

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, vim

I tried opening files with vim using `vim $(cat filelist)` as suggested from this earlier [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72200/open-multiple-files-in-vim-with-a-filelist).

Suppose I have the following file:

```
~/Workspace/bar/foo.cpp
```

Executing `vim $(cat filelist)` from `~/Workspace` correctly opens `foo.cpp` when `filelist` contains `bar/foo.cpp`. However, the command does not open the file when `filelist` contains `~/Workspace/bar/foo.cpp`. I want to know why using the absolute path causes the command to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the order in which the different types of expansions are performed in a shell. The `bash` manpage says:

> Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into words.  There are seven kinds of expansion
> performed: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion,  command  substitution,  arithmetic
> expansion, word splitting, and pathname expansion.

Replacing the `~` is tilde expansion, while your `$(...)` is command substitution. Now you see that after the command substitution is performed, there is no more tilde substitution. With real absolute paths (starting at file system root `/`) it would work.

But you can perform the expansion by yourself with `sed`:

```
vim $(sed "s_~_${HOME}_g" filelist)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quote from the man page, it really helps me understand the underlying mechanics of the commandline.

Comment: @Abhilash: This fails when files or path components have `~` anywhere in their name, which is permitted. Add `^` in front of `~` in your regex matching of pattern space and drop the global flag `g` at the end of the substitution, unless `filelist` contains more than one file record per line, although in this case a new issue would be how to distinguish two consecutive records and `sed` might not be the best tool anymore. Also require the presence of `/` or be ready to deal with legit instances of `~USER/` in fqp of files. In the end I would do `vim $(sed "s_^~/_${HOME}/_" filelist)`.