# Reliable way to open files given by the result of find … -exec grep … {} \+

Tags: grep, find, vim, xargs

I often run commands like this:

```bsh
find … -exec grep … --color=always -l {} \+
```

and sometimes I need to open the matching files in Vim.

But what is the most reliable way to do so?

[One way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5865/164309) seems to be

```bsh
vim $(find … -exec grep … {} \+)
```

Another way seems to make use of `xargs`.

Are there advantages/disvantages/concerns to be aware for these two, and others, if any, methods?

Comment: You have already found that colored output is not supposed to be processed. Can't you simply remove `--color=always`? With `-l` grep only lists matched files anyway, so you really shouldn't need colors.

Comment: After all you're right, adding `-l` and removing `--color=always` takes more or less the same fraction of time. And changing the latter to the former takes even less time. I've modified the question to get some more knowledge about the command substitution approach vs the `xargs` approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit a list of generated files whose names contain spaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597764/how-to-edit-a-list-of-generated-files-whose-names-contain-spaces)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
vim $(find path/ -exec grep -l 'pattern' {} +)
```

is an unquoted command substitution, so word splitting will be performed on whitespace on its result, as well as pathname expansion. I.e., if a file `a b` matches, Vim will incorrectly open `a` and `b`. If a file `*`
matches, alas, that will be expanded to every file in the corresponding directory. An appropriate solution is

```
find path/ -type f -exec grep -q 'pattern' {} \; -exec vim {} +
```

Grep runs in `q`uiet mode: Only its return value is used for each file.  If `0`, a match was found in that file and the file is passed on to Vim.

`{} \;` means one file will be analysed at a time by Grep. If we used `{} +`, all files would be passed as arguments to Grep, and a found match in *any* of those files would result on `0` exit status, so all those files would be opened in Vim. On the other hand, `{} +` is used for Vim so that it each found file goes to one buffer in a single Vim process. You can try changing them to feel the difference.

If you need to speed things up:

- If `'pattern'` is not a regular expression, but only a fixed pattern, add the `-F` flag to Grep.
- `grep -lZ`, Xargs and special shell constructs should also speed-up the process if you have those available, see [Stéphane Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608332).

And [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/597764) are another similar use cases with Xargs, Find and Vim.

Answer (score 6):

With GNU tools (your `--color=always` is a GNU extension already) and a shell with support for Ksh-style process substitution:

```
xargs -r0a <(grep -rlZ pattern .) vim
```

Or:

```
xargs -r0a <(find . ... -exec grep -lZ pattern {} +) vim
```

With `zsh`:

```
vim ${(0)"$(find . ... -exec grep -lZ pattern {} +)"}
```

With `bash` 4.4+:

```
readarray -td '' files < <(find . ... -exec grep -lZ pattern {} +)
vim "${files[@]}"
```

Those minimise the number of `grep` invocations that are performed. The point is to tell `grep` to output the file names NUL-delimited, so they  can be reliably split into separate arguments for `vim` by GNU `xargs -0` or `zsh`'s `0` parameter expansion flag or `bash`'s `readarray -td ''`.

In `zsh`, you could also do:

```
vim ./**/*(...e['grep -q pattern $REPLY'])
```

(where `...` stands in for further qualifiers you may want to add, like for the `find` approach).

That means however that like the approaches that use `find -exec grep -q pattern {} ';'`, one `grep` invocation would be run per file which would make it significantly slower.

Your first approach would work in `zsh` provided you replaced `--color=always` with `-Z` and changed the value of `IFS` to `IFS=$'\0'` from the default of `IFS=$' \r\n\0'`. I wouldn't work in other shells, as they don't support storing NULs in variables, let alone `$IFS` and would also perform filename generation on the words resulting of the splitting which you'd need to disable with `set -o noglob` or `set -f`.

[Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) will give you more tips on how to process the list of files found by `find` reliably.

Answer (score 2):

Two different approaches:

1. Put the results in a quickfix list:

```
find ... -exec grep -Hn {} + >results
vim -q results
```

Or the cleaner (but non-sh)

```
vim -q <(find ... -exec grep -Hn {} +)
```

2. Use `:grep -R` and `:Cfilter`:

```
vim
:grep -R ...
:packadd cfilter
:Cfilter[!]
```

See the relevant `:help` for some of the commands.

Either way, you can navigate matches with `:cnext` and the other `:help quickfix` commands.

Comment: Thank you Ben for sharing a Vim-centric approach. I believe it assumes some restrictions in the filenames (for example, no newline characters), correct?

Comment: @Quasímodo that’s probably correct—but then again, it’s a vim assumption. One might be able to play with errorformat to avoid said assumption.